# Arrow with circle in the middle

Tags: symbols

What is the latex command for a right arrow with a circle in the middle? 
I have tried detexify and the comprehensive latex symbols list but did not find.

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of this symbol?

Answer (score 10):

A simple Ti*k*Z version:

The `\arrowcircle` allows for some `TikZ` options to be specified as optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\arrowcircle}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
    \draw[->] (0,0ex) -- (2em,0ex);
    \draw (1em,0ex) circle (0.7ex);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
Some dummy text \arrowcircle[blue,line width=0.8pt] continues here!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As [symbols-a4.pdf](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) says (table 160, stix arrows), it's `\circleonrightarrow \circleonleftarrow`

It looks like this:

[image]

You can also use boisik package and `\rightarrowcircle`, which looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With traditional methods:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\circlearrow}{}% just in case
\DeclareRobustCommand{\circlearrow}{%
  \mathrel{\vphantom{\rightarrow}\mathpalette\circle@arrow\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\circle@arrow}[2]{%
  \m@th
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth$#1\circ\mkern1mu$\hidewidth\cr
    $#1\longrightarrow$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
A\circlearrow B_{x\circlearrow y}
\]

\end{document}
```

The kern is to correct the optical effect that makes the circle not to appear centered.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\rightarrowfill{\m@th\mathrel-\mkern-6mu\cleaders\hbox{$\mkern-2mu\mathord-\mkern-2mu$}\hfill\mkern-6mu\mathrel\rightarrow}%
\def\circledrightarrow{\put(14,2.5){\circle{10}}{\ooalign{\hb@xt@30\p@{$\rightarrowfill$}}}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\circledrightarrow$ \circledrightarrow
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Arrow with circle]